# Arranging text and image in the same line

Tags: html, css

This question has been answered many times, but none of the solutions work for my problem.
I have some text and image to be aligned linearly (in a single line)

I have http://grab.by/vLz2 and http://grab.by/vLz8

Could someone please help?

Comment: You will better make a jsfiddle instead of screenshot.

Comment: if you're going to bypass a jfiddle, just copy and paste the code here, not screenshots of the code

Comment: Much of the  code is dynamically generated using Javascript. So, I thought this would give a better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the image height is same as font-size.

```
.title{
   position:absolute;
   height: 15%;
   width:100%;
}

#wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    width:80%;
    height:50%;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

#title4{
    font-size:20px;
}

<!-- HTML part -->
<div class="title" id="title4">
    Title
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" 
         style="height:20px;vertical-align:top;"/> 
</div>
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mithiljadhav/k23hg/2)

Answer (score -2):

You need to use floats, so somewhere in your CSS float that image to the right (float: right;)

Comment: Floats are only an option, `<img>` is an inline element so it can be done without floats.